# Best cakephp plugin for sending newsletter (email)

Tags: email, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I want to send newsletter with `cakephp`.
Which plugin is good for it?
[cakeresque](http://cakeresque.kamisama.me/),
[CakePHP Queue Plugin](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue),
[CakePHP Email Queue plugin](https://github.com/nodesagency/cakephp-email-queue),
or etc ...

Comment: Questions like this are not suited to StackOverflow as answers would be very opinionated rather than fact based.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without knowing any context, I'd scratch off the Queue plugin. It is pushing for minimalistic, but it doesn't sound like that is what you want. On the other end, CakeResque seems a bit overkill, and may be too much for your needs. Email Queue plugin seems simple enough to get the job done, but it hasn't been updated in two years, which could potentially cause problems if you aren't careful.

It really depends on what you like more. CakeResque is probably a safe bet, as it seems updated and you will find a lot more support than you might on the open source projects, but I prefer the last one, Email Queue plugin, as it is simple and gets it done fine.

Comment: Please do not answer blatantly off topic questions.

Comment: thanks, it's tThe best explanation that i want

Comment: i want to send 100,000 email at each time. Which method is currect?

Comment: @reza for bulk email you should use https://github.com/nodesagency/cakephp-email-queue . this will send email through cron function